Should I trim the top of my white maple?
My white maple tree is growing sideways near the top because it was previously overcrowded.
Should I trim the top to get it to grow straight again?
Growing zone 8b

Trees usually grow at an angle for some of these reasons:

more light
planted at an angle
strong winds forced the root ball partially out of the ground (unlikely with such a young tree)

Best thing to do is not to cut it back as that will remove the central leader and cause multiple leaders to grow.  These will have a weaker attachment and cause problems later.
If the plant is growing at an angle due to more light in that direction thin back the other trees to allow more light in.
I also recommend getting a long bamboo stake or pole and loosely tying the leaning branch to it at several points with a flexible wide tie.  Old bicycle inner tubes are great for this.   A year or two of being forced upright should correct the lean
